# Why's 0 = probability that the needle exactly span a (hardwood floor) slat?

Tags: probability

Please see the embolded phrase in footnote *. If this probability is possible, why's the probability 0?

> But there’s another solution, discovered by Joseph-Émile Barbier more
> than a century after Buffon’s entry into the Royal Academy. No formal
> calculus is needed; in fact, you don’t need computation of any kind. The
> argument, while a little involved, uses no more than arithmetic and basic
> geometric intuition. And the crucial point is, of all things, the additivity of
> expected value!
>       The first step is to rephrase Buffon’s problem in terms of expected value.
> We can ask: What is the expected *number* of cracks the needle crosses? The
> number Buffon aimed to compute was the probability p that the thrown-down
> needle crosses a crack. Thus there is a probability of 1 − p that the needle
> doesn’t cross any cracks. But if the needle crosses a crack, it crosses *exactly*
> one.* So expected number of crossings is obtained the same way we always
> compute expected value: by summing up each possible number of crossings,
> multiplied by the probability of observing that number. In this case the only
> possibilities are 0 (observed with probability $1 − p$) and 1 (observed with
> probability p) so we add up

> $(1 − p) \times 0 = 0$
> and
> $p × 1 = p$

> and get p. So the expected number of crossings is simply p, the same
> number Buffon computed. We seem to have made no progress. How can we
> figure out the mystery number?
>       When you’re faced with a math problem you don’t know how to do, you’ve
> got two basic options. You can make the problem easier, or you can make it
> harder.

> *You might complain that since the needle is exactly as long as the slat is wide, it is possible that the needle touches two cracks. But this requires that the needle span the slat *exactly*; **it is possible but the probability that it happens is 0**, and we can safely ignore it.

Ellenberg, *How Not to Be Wrong* (2014), pages 217-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Theta$ be a random variable measuring that the angle that the needle makes with the horizontal (perpendicular to all of the slat cracks). By symmetry, we have that $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed from $0$ to $\pi$, or $\Theta\sim U [0,\pi)$.

In a continuous uniform distribution like $U[0,\pi)$, the probability of the variable *exactly equalling* any particular value is zero (whereas the probability of its value falling within a particular interval is proportional to the length of that interval).

Since the needle is as long as the slat is wide, it would have to be perfectly horizontal in order to touch two slats, meaning that $\Theta=0$. But this occurs with a probability of $0$, since there are infinitely many values of $\Theta$ and they are all equally likely (hence the uniform distribution).

Comment: Technically it's $U[0,\pi)$, isn't it? Since the entire issue here is that $0$ is theoretically possible to achieve (and $0$ and $\pi$ denote the same result, so including both of them isn't right either). Usually the distinction is entirely moot, but not, I would say, in this case. Also, in addition to the angle being

Comment: @Arthur As I understand it, the parentheses in $U(0,\pi)$ represent function notation, not the open interval $(0,\pi)$. Perhaps I am mistaken...?

Comment: @Arthur Nevermind, I googled it and it turns out I had my notation wrong, you're right. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Now that you say it, I'm not sure. I just thought of it like the notation $C^0[0,\pi)$, the set of continuous functions on the interval. There it definitely is an interval and not function notation. However, in the case of probability distribution, you rarely care about the exact end points, so it usually matters little what exactly it means. As opposed to the function space, where the inclusion of the end point is a major limitation on what functions are included.

Comment: Oh, right. Good on you for actually looking it up. Also, back to the meat of your answer, note that even if you do get the angle exactly right, even that's not enough, as the position is just as problematic as the angle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems counter-intuitive and unreal that an event can have probability $0$ yet be possible.  It is unreal, it occurs only in the mathematical world of absolute precision.  For example, in the mathematical world, we have a positive real number whose square is exactly $2$.  Could we observe that in the real world?  Well, we could draw a square $1$ metre by $1$ metre and measure its diagonal.  However, we would not be able to measure it with absolute precision.  Even if we measure it to nano-metre or pico-metre precision, we would just get a number whose square was close to $2$.

Back to your case.  If we accept that the measurements of the needle and slat do not have absolute precision then the weirdness goes away.  Instead, we have an event that is possible but very unlikely which is much less weird.

Note that I have not invoked the weirdness of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle.  Even pre-quantum physics has limited precision.